# How to work with freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I should setup a VOIP network. I installed Virtualbox and install ubuntu server on a virtual machine and installed freeswitch on it. I also installed Ekiga softphone on my ubuntu desktop. Now , I need a manual or tutorial to help me how to work with freeswtich, how connect my softphones to my PBX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an excellent [book](http://www.packtpub.com/freeswitch-1-0-6-build-robust-high-performance-telephony-systems/book) which explains the FreeSWITCH in details. You need to read that before you go any further.

as an alternative, you can, of course, order consultancy and training from whomever is able to offer it

Comment: I changed my Os. I installed CentOS,freeswitch and bluebox. May you introduce source for configuring freestich with bluebox to me?

Comment: you need to read the book or hire a system administrator who can dig through bluebox source code. I don't think you get much of documentation on bluebox.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend FusionPBX if you are looking for a easy to manage open-source PBX.

**For phone numbers**, use Google Talk and get free numbers. XMPP settings are easy in FusionPBX

**Router**: make sure the following ports are open
1719     UDP     H.323 Gatekeeper RAS port
1720     TCP     H.323 Call Signaling
3478     UDP     STUN service    Used for NAT traversal
3479     UDP     STUN service    Used for NAT traversal
5002     TCP     MLP protocol server
5003     UDP     Neighborhood service
5060     UDP & TCP   SIP UAS     Used for SIP signaling
5070     UDP & TCP   SIP UAS     Used for SIP signaling
5080     UDP & TCP   SIP UAS     Used for SIP signaling
8021     TCP     ESL     Used for mod_event_socket
16384-32768  UDP     RTP/ RTCP multimedia streaming
 Make sure to disable the routers SIP/ALG services and to assign your in-home VoIP server it's own IP Address slot on your router. Turn on your routers UpNP so you dont stress your bandwidth calling to stun servers to get an external ip address. Make sure you turn on port forwarding to point the ports above, along with port 80 to your voip server IP.

**VoIP server**: make sure you modify IPtables as freeswitch needs. find a DoS protection shell script to daemonize because YOU WILL be spammed by Canada @ yourserver.com or whoever trying to register, and when this happens, you will have to restart FS :( Make sure you enable mod_dingaling in FS if you are going to use Google Talk servers. Mind your **user contexts** in your FS settings for the sip profiles or your calls will die as soon as you dial.

**One-Way audio problems:**

Make sure your endpoints are in the same context;

make sure your phones register using the external ip address (DynDNS);

Check your codec negotiation;

Router firewall could be blocking you. Use WireShark to check for dropped packages/SIP errors. Enable SIP debugging in the fs_cli to see you SIP debug info

If using google talk, you need to send a DTMF of **1** to bridge the audio. you can set this action in your dialplan or in a android (Java) app, SipAudioCall.sendDTMF(1);

Toggle early-media settings in FS

Toggle the port the softphone has registered on from internal port to external port